# How to run hooks in linux git server

Tags: git, hook, githooks

I have a problem with run Git hooks in Git server. My file is `post-receive` in `/projects/project.git/hooks/`. This file should always start with the push on server. My problem is that this file does not start.

Comment: is your hook file in your local repo or in the remote server?

Comment: Is it executable? What have you done to debug the problem? How do you know it does not start?

Comment: Yes, this file is executable. When I run the file manually done everything correctly. After submission of the new file will not be added to the folder where you have. Hook file is in remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Git hooks are scripts that Git executes before or after events such as: commit, push, and receive. Git hooks are a built-in feature and usually being run locally, such as: pre-commit; pre-receive; post-commit; post-receive. Every Git repository has a [.git/hooks](http://githooks.com/) folder with a script for each hook you can bind to. You're free to change or update these scripts as necessary, and Git will execute them when those events occur.